# what is the meaning of this syntax of size_t?

Tags: c++, lzma

I found this line during debugging lzma decompression but I can not understand what is this line meaning???

```
 SizeT inSizeCur = inSize, outSizeCur, dicPos;
```

I know that `inSizeCur` is variable of type `SizeT` which is assigned the value of `inSize`.
but what are `, outSizeCur, dicPos`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is declaring 3 variables having type `SizeT`. It is equivalent to:

```
SizeT inSizeCur = inSize;
SizeT outSizeCur;
SizeT dicPos;
```

Comment: the other 2 variables are "default initialized"

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili depending on where that declaration is, they could be uninitialised

Comment: @Caleth `int a;` in a function scope leaves `a` "default initialized with an indeterminate value".